# TypeError: _reactNative.NativeModules.RNDatePickerAndroid.dismiss is not a function

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I am trying to show `Date Picker`. I installed it and put it in render function to test. `Date Picker` is visible but there is an error also.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _reactNative.NativeModules.RNDatePickerAndroid.dismiss is not a function. (In '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNDatePickerAndroid.dismiss()', '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNDatePickerAndroid.dismiss' is undefined)]
```

Code:

```
    <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={this.state.date}
          mode="date"
          display="default"
          onChange={this.onDateChange}
        />
```

Comment: There seems to be a whole thread on this here: https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/issues/502

Answer (score 0):

Which version of @react-native-community/datetimepicker are you using?

I am not sure the cause of the warning, but in my case the warning did disappeared after I downgraded the version of @react-native-community/datetimepicker to 3.0.2.